# Sql Server is calculating computed field even though it is persisted

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have created a computed field for a json document like that:

```
...,
[vId]  AS (CONVERT([bigint],json_value([Value],'$.Id'))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [vId] DESC
)
```

Then I run a simple query:

```
SELECT vId FROM MyTable WHERE vId = 100
```

After I checked the execution plan I was surprised to find out that after an index seek sql server performs `Compute Scalar` where it seems to calculate vId (is listed in Output List).

Shouldn't SQL Server already have access to the value since it is persisted?

Comment: [Properly Persisted Computed Columns](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns) `"The Compute Scalars do nothing useful and would be cleaned up if the optimizer were a bit tidier around the house"`

Comment: It seems another quote explains it better: `The lack of optimizer cost model support means SQL Server assigns a small fixed cost to scalar computations, regardless of complexity or implementation. As a consequence, the server often decides to recompute a stored computed column value instead of reading the persisted or indexed value directly. This is particularly painful when the computed expression is expensive, for example when it involves calling a scalar user-defined function.` You can just add this as an answer then :)

Comment: Trace flag 176 sorts this out, as mentioned in that article by @PaulWhite. Use at your own risk